# How to change Taskbar and Shortcut Icon run time?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to change application Taskbar and Shortcut Icon. User wants to need flexibility to change icon at run time.

`this.Icon =new Icon("Images/A.ico");`

It will change only window title icon at run time. Please suggest how to achieve programmatically.

Thanks,
Mahendra

Comment: you mean, you want to change desktop shortcut icon?

Comment: Yes Desktop Shortcut and taskbar as well

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for you to create deesktop shortcut

Full code [here](http://www.sorrowman.org/c-sharp-programmer/url-link-to-desktop.html)

```
using System.IO;
//...//

private void appShortcutToDesktop(string linkName)
{
  string deskDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);

  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(deskDir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
  {
    string app = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
    writer.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + app);
    writer.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
    string icon = app.Replace('\\', '/');
    writer.WriteLine("IconFile=" + icon);
    writer.Flush();
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply.It just create desktop shortcut it is not able to change the desktop shortcut icon. At where to set the icon path in above function?